# is there's a way to assign href with an id from a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a javascript function to add a navbar dynamically and I want when I click on the links to be directed to the desired section.

```
    const navbuild = function() {
    for( let i = 0; i < sectionName.length; i++){
         let navitems = document.createElement("li")
        navAddress = document.createElement("a");
        navTextNode = document.createTextNode (sectionName[i].dataset.nav);
        navAddress.appendChild(navTextNode);
        navAddress.href= sectionName[i].id;
        navAddress.classList.add(sectionName[i].id);
        if(sectionName[i] == sectionName[0]){
            navAddress.classList.add("active");
        }
        navitems.appendChild(navAddress);
        navMenu.appendChild(navitems);
    }
};
```

the problem is i can't use # and the variable at the same time it's either
`navAddress.href= sectionName[i].id;` that works but directs me to no where or
`navAddress.href= #sectionName[i].id;` which is an error.

Comment: try it `avAddress.href=  '#' + sectionName[i].id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate them using + operator:

```
navAddress.href="#"+sectionName[i].id;
```